# Rails routes to documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, documentation-generation

I use rails 4 for a restFUL API and would like to use http://apidocjs.com/ as i did with php.
I could generate my api documentation in /doc but after I'm wondering what is the best "rails way" to route to this doc. Should I create a controller or just routes to my html file like :

```
get '/doc', :to => redirect('/doc/index.html')
```

I tried it but I get

```
No route matches [GET] "/doc/index.html"
```

So what is the best way to do that ? I feel like I don't think "rails way"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your documentation is completely generated and just static html, you can simply place it within your `public` folder and it will be routed automatically. In other words, you can create the `docs` folder within the `public` folder and then access your pages via

```
http://example.com/docs/index.html
```

In development this would be

```
http://localhost:3000/docs/index.html
```

If you're looking for something more robust, I'd highly recommend [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) by thoughtbot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this provided you have controller named as docs and action named as index.

```
 get 'docs', :to => 'docs#index', :as => 'doc'
```

Comment: Yeah i thought about this solution but create a controller just to show my doc is not too much ? =/

Answer (score 0):

```
resource :doc, only: :show
```

Then create this file

```
/app/views/docs/show.html
```

No controller needed

The URL will be

```
/doc
```